# How Would One Get Values From A Class To Another Using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to programing in swift and would like to know how to get values from a .swift file to another. I will give you an example:

There are two .swift files and two view controllers. The first view controller is named ViewController and the second RecievedInfo. ViewController contains two vars: LevelNumber, and DifficultyNumber. Both of these vars are of type Int. Then there are three level IBACTIONS titled: L1, L2, and L3. They change the value of LevelNumber with the corresponding number. Next we have three difficulties that are also IBActions: easy, medium, and hard. They all contain a new value for DifficultyNumber corresponding to their title in order. Here is what we have below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var LevelNumber: Int!
var DifficultyNumber: Int!

@IBAction func Level1(sender: AnyObject) {
    LevelNumber = 1
}

@IBAction func Level2(sender: AnyObject) {
    LevelNumber = 2
}

@IBAction func Level3(sender: AnyObject) {
    LevelNumber = 3
}
/////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////
@IBAction func Easy(sender: AnyObject) {
    DifficultyNumber = 1
}

@IBAction func Medium(sender: AnyObject) {
    DifficultyNumber = 2
}

@IBAction func Hard(sender: AnyObject) {
    DifficultyNumber = 3
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I used the slashes to separate the 2 groups.
In RecievedInfo we have created a label titled InformationLabel and that is all:

```
import UIKit

class RecievedInfo: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var InformationLabel: UILabel!

}
```

I would like someone to tell me how to print out the information from ViewController (LevelNumber and DifficultyNumber) to RecievedInfo.

I know that I could create multiple view controllers or plists but please stay away from those please. All recommendations welcome! Let me know if I need to describe anything more.

Comment: You don't get values from one file to another. You get values from one class instance to another.

Comment: You appear to be approaching this from the wrong angle.  What you will need to learn is how to navigate "segue" between view controllers.  Given that you are starting off, I recommend the Stanford iOS lecture series, which covers this in great clarity.  You can find that online or in iTunes U.  If you want to jump into the deep end, google prepareForSegue.

Comment: I agree with WenchenHuang's answer. The easiest for you would probably be passing the data through segues. Although... and I will get flamed for this... I'm a fan of global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to pass data

1.use delegate design pattern

2.use NSNotificationCenter

3.use Segue's

**Update:**

http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/

This link contains detail information you want

Comment: Could you give me an example of using a segue? This would be very helpful.

Comment: See the link I update,it will show you how to use delegate and segues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I followed to tutorial, almost finished it but there's some bug I can't figure out yet.